# Given a docker container ID how can I get the cgroup of that container?

Tags: docker, cgroups

When I have a docker container ID or name retrieved by `docker ps`, how can I quickly get the cgroup associated with that container. I know I can find the `pid` of the process running in the container, and then inspect `/proc/<pid>/cgroups`, but this is cumber some, because I first need to identify the PID on the host for the process running in the container.

**Update:**
My use case is that I want to check the current resource consumption of the cgroup via `systemd-cgtop <cgroup>`, e.g:

```
systemd-cgtop /kubepods/besteffort/podxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In my case I am using Kubernetes, so maybe in addition to Docker there are also Kubernetes specific aspects involved.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this from Docker official site [Find the cgroup for a given container?](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#find-the-cgroup-for-a-given-container)

Comment: This particular link I had not seen, but it helps a bit. The cgroups are in a subfolder nested somewhere under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods/.../<containerID>`. I could come up with a script that looks up the cgroup corresponding to the container ID but I was kind of hoping that there already exists a convenient cli command for that.